# Crystal: a good way for method options

Tags: crystal-lang

I need to pass some options to a method, some of these options are optional (something like Object destructuring in JS).

My current code:

```
def initialize( arg1 : String, options = {} of Symbol => String )
  opt = MyClass.get_option options, :opt1
  @opt1 = !opt.empty? ? opt : "Def value"
  opt = MyClass.get_option options, :opt2
  @opt2 = !opt.empty? ? opt : "False"
  # ...
end
def self.get_option( options, key : Symbol )
  ( options && options[key]? ) ? options[key].strip : ""
end
```

And I call it: `MyClass.new "Arg", { opt2: "True", opt4: "123" }`

It works but I'm looking for a better way. It would be useful to set the type of each option and to have default values directly in the function signature.

Using a [NamedTuple](https://crystal-lang.org/api/NamedTuple.html) seems a good way but I had problems with optional values - `options : NamedTuple( opt1: String, opt2: Bool, opt3: String, opt4: Int ) | Nil = nil`

Another way that I tried is with a struct but it seems to complicate the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crystal has optional and named method arguments as core language features, and does not require writing special code for handling the arguments. See the official documentation about [Method arguments](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/default_values_named_arguments_splats_tuples_and_overloading.html). In particular, here is an example:

```
def method(arg1 : String, *, opt1 = "Def value", opt2 = false)
```

The asterisk is not always needed, it only ensures that the following optional arguments can *only* be passed by name:

```
method("test", opt1: "other value", opt2: false)
```

Comment: I'm not trying to mimick other's langs patterns. Simply I'm looking for a good way to pass a hash of options and I'm learning the language

Comment: You don't pass a hash of options in Crystal. It might be very common in Ruby, but in Crystal (or in general in any statically typed language) you'll have a hard time doing that. One choice is to define a struct that has default values and let users pass a struct where only some fields are customized.

Comment: @asterite: good point, I'm used to Ruby and sometimes I tend to build things thinking in Ruby